# in rails, when creating factorygirl for a model, shoudn't model's before_create be invoked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

My app has a Phone model, and one of the fields is .guid which is set with `before_create :set_guid` (which generates a random string and puts it in the guid field when the model is created).

My factory for phone looks like:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :phone do |f|
    f.phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
  end
end
```

This simple test to create a phone fails my model's validation because the guid is blank:

```
describe Phone do
  it "has a valid factory"  do
    FactoryGirl.create(:phone).should be_valid
  end
```

I could of course manually stuff the guid field in the Factory definition, but isn't the point of the Factory to run the model's normal validations and callbacks to ensure they are working?

Clearly I am missing something - what IS the right way to use FactoryGirl to create instance of a model that properly exercises before_create callbacks that geenrate guids etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a model Phone with an attribute phone?

All that aside, there is factory girl [callbacks in their Getting Started](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks).

```
factory :user do
  callback(:after_stub, :before_create) { do_something }
  after(:stub, :create) { do_something_else }
  before(:create, :custom) { do_a_third_thing }
end
```

Something like the before(:create) may work for you.

Can't you just hard code a guid in the default Factory as well? i mean you just want to test it once to see if it works, and then the rest is just ballast, cause you want working tests.

Comment: tried that but can't figure out the 'do_a_third_thing' or whether I ALSO need a callback()... when I use before(:create) { f.set_guid } nothing seems to happen.

Comment: And I'm actually trying to test the callbacks using the factory, to ensure my code really is creating proper guids.

Comment: Yeah i hear ya man, It's hard some days with stuff like this. So when you leave it out and just do `FactoryGirl.create(:phone)` your guid is still  blank right?

Comment: Thx for the help ... the test was doing exactly what I needed... my validation was, in fact, wrong... I was setting my guid with before_create and SHOULD have been doing it before_validation_on_create  d'oh!